# MarshalDirectiveException

Tags: dllimport

I would like use unmanaged code from C in C#.

I built a DLL with C code with this functions:

```
struct GetPluginData
{
 int data[22];
};

DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) GetPluginData GetDataArray(int number);
```

In C# I've got this code:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
        public unsafe struct GetPluginData
        {
            /// int[22]
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 22, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4)]
            public int[] data;
        }

[DllImport("RBRPlugin.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "GetDataArray")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public static extern GetPluginData GetDataArray(int number);
```

In button event or othe place code, I wrote this:

```
GetPluginData tes = GetDataArray(1);
```

And I'm getting the error: The type signature of this method is not PInvoke compatible.

I'm looking for information throught google, but no result found...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems:

- CallingConvertion.StdCall is incorrect, you didn't declare the function __stdcall in the C code.  Make it CallingConvention.Cdecl.
- Remove the [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] attribute, it is incorrect.  UnmanagedType.Struct is rather unintuitive and not actually used on structs.
- Remove the Pack attribute property, it is very unlikely to be correct albeit harmless here.  Default packing in the C compiler is 8 unless you used #pragma pack or the /Zp compile option.
- The pinvoke marshaller doesn't support returning a struct as a function return value that contains an embedded array.  The source of the exception.  Declare it as `fixed int data[22]` instead.

Comment: The correct code is:         [DllImport("RBRPlugin.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "GetDataArray")]
        public static extern GetPluginData GetDataArray(int number);
        
        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct GetPluginData
        {
            public unsafe fixed int data[22];
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here better, the correct code is:

```
[DllImport("RBRPlugin.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "GetDataArray")]
public static extern GetPluginData GetDataArray(int number);

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GetPluginData
{
    public unsafe fixed int data[22];
}

public GetPluginData temp1 = new GetPluginData();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetPluginData test = GetDataArray(1);
    temp1 = test;
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (GetPluginData* p = &temp1)
        {
            p->data[0] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```